# Using a listbox to declare a parameter in my sql statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, parameters, sql-injection

I have a list box that allows multiple values to be selected.

Here is my query for my gridview

```
saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales, B601SalesAsOF.Sales AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =@Dyyyy) AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) and B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR in (@regions)order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
```

Here is my query for my listbox

```
listcmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER"
```

I want the user to select all the regions they want to query in the gridview.

as of now i am putting each selected list item into a textbox

```
Function list()
    Dim li As ListItem
       For Each li In ListBox1.Items
         If li.Selected Then
            TextBox1.Text &= "'" & li.Text & "' ," & vbCrLf
       End If
Next
End Function
```

then before the query is run i use
   to subtract the final , so i dont get an error and i have to use textbox1.text in my query and not the parameter. that is slower and sql injection, i need help doing this a better way thanks

```
If TextBox1.Text.EndsWith(",") Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
            End If
```

Comment: You can't use your comma separated list as parameter for your select-command. You will have to write a table-valued-function that iterates your parameters in your database(MS-SQL-Server?): http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV

Comment: so a stored procedure is inevitable, haha i have never used one

Comment: If you want no sql-injection, yes. Also i would recommend not to use the Region-Text but the ID of the Region for the select-command. It is essential faster to select a primary key than a varchar column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your comma separated list as parameter for your select-command. You will have to write a table-valued-function that iterates your parameters in your database(MS-SQL-Server?): [Comma-separated List of Values](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV)

```
CREATE FUNCTION iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: thanks so this function would go into my stored procedure, or is this a function in my database that i can call in my sql statements

Comment: i know its a dumb question, but im very new at dealing with databases

Comment: This is a table-value-function. It returns a Table representation of your comma separated list. So you can query and join it like a normal table from everywhere. You should take the time to learn it ;-)

Comment: o so thats awesome, i can use this in my in statement of my query, but how do i relate my listbox to it